# How to generate timeseries data into table in Oracle PL/SQL between two date using interval 1 minute?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper

I am new in this topic. In my setup Oracle 12c Standard Edition database and PL/SQL Developer.

I have a table which has the following structure:

```
int id; 
timestamp time_mon;
double price;
```

I need to insert data into a table which generate with some period such as 02.01.2018 00:00 - 02.01.2019 00:00 with an interval of 5 minutes. I cannot cope with this task. Please help me and show the SQL code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean 02.01.2018 = 2 January, this could be a way:

```
insert into yourTable(id, time_mon, price)
select ??? as id,                                                      -- to be completed
       date '2018-01-02' + interval '5' minute * (level -1) as time_mon,
       ??? as price                                                    -- to be completed
from dual
connect by date '2018-01-02' + interval '5' minute * (level -1) <= date '2019-01-02'
```

Comment: You just need to add the insert part, just showed. regarding the id and price, you need to know which values you need to insert